# How Can I validate pdf in qtp ..?

Tags: validation, vbscript, qtp

I need to validate the PDFs in qtp. Does anyone have any ideas other than copying data to the clipboard and then from clipboard to a text file to compare?

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "validate"? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Comparing Both Pdf's and finding out difference's and to do this is there any other way ..??? I need to automate this whole comparison of pdf and check if they are same or different . i have tried to fetch directly data from pdf and trying to compare them without copying it to clipboard , but i couldn't do it . if i can check them line by line it would be perfect .. these things also i tried but couldnt do it ... someway or other i need to use some text file or clipboard to copy the data  fetched .. problem i have is like clipboard(or)Notepad crashes...

Answer (score 1):

For checking if two PDFs are identical you could shell out to `fc`:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34)
End Function

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

pdf1 = "C:\path\to\some.pdf"
pdf2 = "C:\path\to\other.pdf"

result = sh.Run("fc /b " & qq(pdf1) & " " & qq(pdf2), 0, True)

If result = 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "PDFs are equal."
Else
  WScript.Echo "PDFs are not equal."
End If
```

`qq()` is a quoting function to simplify putting double quotes around a path (in case it contains spaces).

Comment: +1 since this answers the question. Unfortunately, OP has post-specified in a different answer´s comment that there are differences to ignore, which is exactly what we were asking about in the question comments, getting no answer. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UFT 11.50 (UFT is QTP's new name) then [file content checkpoints](http://qtp.blogspot.in/2013/01/file-content-checkpoint.html) would seem to be a perfect fit for you needs.

If you're using an older version... why not upgrade :)

Comment: Thanks u So much For the Suggestion.. But is there any other way to compare pdf's , i need to automate the whole process, and also ignore some data in pdf .. it's better if we compare pdf line by line.. so i can get the difference's ..

Comment: @saddy both the features you ask for (ignore some lines and do line by line comparrison) are available in file content checkpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. Use the free utility pdf2txt.ext to convert pdf to txt and do a line by line compare
2. Use Acrobat Adobe api which gives some flexibility in retrieving pdf content. It can be accessed from http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/access.pdf
3. Get the source of the pdf file which usually is an xml file, and validate that xml file instead of pdf file.